# Solr SynonymGraphFilterFactory error on import

Tags: solr

After upgrading to Solr 7.2 import started to log errors for some documents.

Field that returns errors:

```
   <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /> 
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

During the import below error is returned for some of the records:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id XXXXX to the index; possible analysis error: startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, and offsets must not go backwards startOffset=2874,endOffset=2878,lastStartOffset=2879 for field 'XXXXX'
at g.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:226)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:936)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:616)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:80)
```

It is related to the

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
```

If I remove this it works fine, previously we were using:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

and it was working fine, but the **SynonymFilterFactory** is not longer supported on the Solr 7.X., it has been replaced with **SynonymGraphFilterFactory**, I have added **FlattenGraphFilterFactory** as suggested.

If the synoyms.txt file is updated from:

*word, synonym1, synonym2*

to

*word => synonym1, synonym2*

all is working fine, but

*word => word, synonym1, synonym2*  - does not work.

I am not sure why Solr returns those errors?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Adding solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory  after the call 
to  WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory solved my issue,
 as per WebsterHomer suggestion (http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-SynonymGraphFilterFactory-error-on-import-td4378265.html)